# concat string values in multiple dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

suppose I have a list of dicts (where each dict has the same keys) like this:

```
list_of_dicts = [
    {'Id': 4726, 'Body': 'Hello from John', 'Title': None, 'Comments': 'Dallas. '},
    {'Id': 4726, 'Body': 'Hello from Mary', 'Title': None, 'Comments': "Austin"},
    {'Id': 4726, 'Body': 'Hello from Dylan', 'Title': None, 'Comments': "Boston"},
]
```

I need to concat only the Body, Title and Comments part and return a single dict, like this:

```
{'Id': 4726, 'Body': 'Hello from John Hello from Mary Hello from Dylan', 'Title': None, 'Comments': 'Dallas. Austin Boston'}
```

Please note, Title is None. So, we have to be careful there. This is what I have done so far...but, failing somewhere...I cannot see where...

```
    keys = set().union(*list_of_dicts)
    print(keys)
    k_value = list_of_dicts[0]['Id']
    d_dict = {k: " ".join(str(dic.get(k, '')) for dic in list_of_dicts) for k in keys if k != 'Id'}

    merged_dict = {'Id': k_value}
    merged_dict.update(d_dict)
```

But, the above returns this ...which I do not like:

```
Final Merged Dict: {'Id': 4726, 'Body': 'Hello from John Hello from Mary Hello from Dylan', 'Title': 'None None None', 'Comments': 'Dallas. Austin Boston'}
```

Comment: Is it always `Title` that has the value `None`, or do you need to be able to ignore this value in any element?

Comment: Title has None sometimes and sometimes it has a legit string. I should not ignore the value of Title. I tried filter(None, ...) ...

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd remove `Id` from `keys` to avoid having to skip it in the dictionary comprehension, and use a simple assignment rather than `.update()` at the end.

In the argument to `join`, filter out when `dic[k]` is None. And if the `join` results in an empty string (because all the values are `None`), convert that to `None` in the final result.

```
keys = set().union(*list_of_dicts)
keys.remove('Id')
print(keys)
k_value = list_of_dicts[0]['Id']
d_dict = {k: (" ".join(str(dic[k]) for dic in list_of_dicts if k in dic and dic[k] is not None) or None) for k in keys}
d_dict['Id'] = k_value

print(d_dict)
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/HlUacl)

Comment: I had fixed it in my demo, but not the answer. `.remove()` modifies the set in place, it doesn't return the set.

Answer (score 1):

As you parse your list of dictionaries, you can store the intermediate results in `defaultdict` objects to hold a list of the string values. Once all the dictionaries have been parsed, you can then join together the strings.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd_body = defaultdict(list)
dd_comments = defaultdict(list)
dd_titles = defaultdict(list)

for row in list_of_dicts:
    dd_body[row['Id']].append(row['Body'])
    dd_comments[row['Id']].append(row['Comments'])
    dd_titles[row['Id']].append(row['Title'] or '')  # Effectively removes `None`.

result = []
for id_ in dd_body:  # All three dictionaries have the same keys.
    body = ' '.join(dd_body[id_]).strip()
    comments = ' '.join(dd_comments[id_]).strip()
    titles = ' '.join(dd_titles[id_]).strip() or None
    result.append({'Id': id_, 'Body': body, 'Title': titles, 'Comments': comments})
>>> result
[{'Id': 4726,
  'Body': 'Hello from John Hello from Mary Hello from Dylan',
  'Title': None,
  'Comments': 'Dallas.  Austin Boston'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Less Pythonic then other answers but I like to think that it is easy to understand.

```
body, title, comments = "", "", ""
list_of_dicts=[
    {'Id': 4726, 'Body': 'Hello from John', 'Title': None, 'Comments': 'Dallas. '},
    {'Id': 4726, 'Body': 'Hello from Mary', 'Title': None, 'Comments': "Austin"},
    {'Id': 4726, 'Body': 'Hello from Dylan', 'Title': None, 'Comments': "Boston"},
]

id = list_of_dicts[0]['Id']

for dict in list_of_dicts:
    if dict['Body'] is not None:
        body=body + dict['Body']

    if dict['Title'] is not None:
        title=title + dict['Title']

    if dict ['Comments'] is not None:
        comments=comments + dict['Comments']

if title == "":
    title = None

if body == "":
    body = None

if comments == "":
    comments = None

record = {'Id': id, 'Body': body, 'Title': title, 'Comments': comments}
```

If only Title field has a option of being None then it can be shortened by removing the checks on the other fields.

```
body, title, comments = "", "", ""
list_of_dicts=[
    {'Id': 4726, 'Body': 'Hello from John', 'Title': None, 'Comments': 'Dallas. '},
    {'Id': 4726, 'Body': 'Hello from Mary', 'Title': None, 'Comments': "Austin"},
    {'Id': 4726, 'Body': 'Hello from Dylan', 'Title': None, 'Comments': "Boston"}]

id = list_of_dicts[0]['Id']

for dict in list_of_dicts:
    body=body + dict['Body']
    comments=comments + dict['Comments']

    if dict['Title'] is not None:
        title=title + dict['Title']

if title == "":
    title = None

record = {'Id': id, 'Body': body, 'Title': title, 'Comments': comments}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this type of data manipulations `pandas` is your friend.

```
import pandas as pd

# Your list of dictionaries.
list_of_dicts = [
{'Id': 4726, 'Body': 'Hello from John', 'Title': None, 'Comments': 'Dallas. '},
{'Id': 4726, 'Body': 'Hello from Mary', 'Title': None, 'Comments': "Austin"},
{'Id': 4726, 'Body': 'Hello from Dylan', 'Title': None, 'Comments': "Boston"},
]

# Can be read into a pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)

# Do a database style groupby() and apply the function that you want to each group
group_transformed_df = df.groupby('Id').agg(lambda x: ' '.join(x)).reset_index() # I do reset_index to get a normal DataFrame back.

# DataFrame() -> dict
output_dict = group_transformed_df.to_dict('records')
```

There are many types of dicts you can get from a DataFrame. You want the `records` option.

Comment: Just saw OP's `None` type column that pandas.groupby ignores. The above solution doesn't handle that.